# how to invoke ws-security/wss4j CXF webclient on weblogic 12c

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws, weblogic12c, cxf-client

I am not sure I have the right understanding of wssecurity yet so please correct me in the order I need to do things, I will try explain my issue.

I am trying to implement jaxws client from a policy enabled wsdl, policy looks this:

```
   <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="AsymmetricX509TokensWithUntPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:UsernameToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SupportingTokens>
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic128/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Lax/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                    <sp:ProtectTokens/>
                    <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <sp:SignedParts>
                <sp:Body/>
                <sp:Header Name="Timestamp" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"/>
            </sp:SignedParts>
            <sp:Wss11>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Wss11>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

I succeded in creating a standalone cxf client communicating with the secured webservice mainly because of these dependencies in cxf framework

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

These has automatic nature of providing a header and do a lot of stuff behind the scene that I dont understand, but it works. My setup for the client is simpel:

```
        Map ctx = ((BindingProvider) webServicePortType).getRequestContext();

    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try (InputStream resourceStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(signaturePropertyFilePath)) {
        props.load(resourceStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "IOException: Unresolvable signature property filepath: " + signaturePropertyFilePath, e);
    }
    props.forEach((k, v) -> {
        ctx.put(k.toString(), v);
    });
    ctx.put(SecurityConstants.CALLBACK_HANDLER, callBackHandler);

    ctx.put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_PROPERTIES, signaturePropertyFilePath);
```

Now my issue, I have seen it work, so I happily move my client to a webapplication running on weblogic 12c, but now things goes wrong. The nice automatic nature of cxf-rt-ws-policy now disappears and I get soap request without header that causes errors:

```
These policy alternatives can not be satisfied:
```

{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}UsernameToken: The received token does not match the token inclusion requirement
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}AsymmetricBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}InitiatorToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}X509Token: The received token does not match the token inclusion requirement
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}IncludeTimestamp
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}ProtectTokens
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SignedParts: {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Body not SIGNED

The result of no header.

Luckily I dont have any problems running cxf clients on weblogic in general, as long the webservices has no security demands. There is no spring or spring bootstrap involved in my working standalone client, maybe cxf has spring invoked in itself but I dont help.

"PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistryImpl" taken from cxf framework stops working when running on weblogic. I suspect it has to do with the cxf bus-extensions.txt working differently when running in a container. Spring is not available in the webapplication on weblogic, sorry. But my standalone works fine without any spring. Anyone on cxf framework please help ! :)

So why does it work standalone and not when running in a container. Can anyone help?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an alternative solution. The nice automatic injection behavior of the ws-security header that works on my standalone never came to work with weblogic 12. Instead I had to configure it manually and make weblogic use a different implementation of JAXBContextFactory and not its own moxy impl. Had problems with moxy even though cxf claimed compatibility with moxy.

1. Classpath create following file META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
2. Add text "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory" to file
3. Create a signature property file:

   > ```
   > security.username=151413  
   > security.password=NA   
   > security.signature.username=sisprivatekey
   > org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
   > org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
   > org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=changeit
   > org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.private.password=changeit
   > org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=KeyStore.jks
   > ```
4. Create a callbackhandler

   ```
       CallbackHandler cpc = new CallbackHandler() {

       @Override
       public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {

           for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {

               WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[i];

               if (pc.getUsage() == WSPasswordCallback.SIGNATURE
                       || pc.getUsage() == WSPasswordCallback.DECRYPT) {


                       pc.setPassword("changeit");
               } else {
                   pc.setPassword("NA");
               }
           }
       }

   };
   ```
5. Setup wss4j/ws-security manually:

   ```
       Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(webServicePortType);

   Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();

   outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN + " "
           + WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP + " " + WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE);
   outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, user);
   outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, callBackHandler);
   outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
   outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, signaturePropertyFilePath);
   outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");
   outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_PARTS,
           "{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body;{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp");

   client.getOutInterceptors().add(new WSS4JStaxOutInterceptor(outProps));
   ```
6. Done.